# Fragment page invalids findViewByID

Tags: java

I am very new to java so pardon any mistakes here. I'm trying to create an intent for one of my buttons which is in a fragment page. However, the layout of a fragment file is different from a regular java class file. My `findViewByID` button is invalid and I can't continue with my intent.

I guess that the issue has to do with either my constructor or the position of my code. I'm aware that similar questions have been asked. However, I neither  understand those solution nor the background of the question.

```java
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button trending_button;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        trending_button = findViewByID(R.id.trending_button);
    }
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be statements following a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement ends the method and the FindViewByID is never called. Place your FindViewByID call before the return statement

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    trending_button = findViewByID(R.id.trending_button);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to work either. The findViewByID still is invalid

Comment: Not a lot to work with here. If the trending_button is a local variable in the fragment, then the best way to initialize it is inside the** OnViewCreated** method. 

Each fragment first calls the **OnCreate** and then calls the **onViewCreated** method.

You may also have to typeCast the results of the findViewById if you are expecting anything other than a view.  trending_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id,trending_button);